# Error screen presenter should be present - Youtube android player api

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, video-streaming, android-youtube-api

I a using youtube andoird player API. Video is not playing in the player.
In the player screen error showing that - "There was a problem with server [400] (playback ID XXXXXXX) Tap to retry"
and in the log - "Error screen presenter should be present "
When i click on try or reload this screen, error is coming everytime.
Any solution?

YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerSupportFragment = this.youTubePlayerFragment;
if (youTubePlayerSupportFragment != null) {
youTubePlayerSupportFragment.initialize(Constant.YOUTUBE_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

```
            @Override // com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    NewSeriesDescActivity newSeriesDescActivity = NewSeriesDescActivity.this;
                    newSeriesDescActivity.youTubePlayer = player;
                    newSeriesDescActivity.youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
                    NewSeriesDescActivity.this.youTubePlayer.cueVideo("zu1ZOm6SmdQ");
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        /* class uautv.net.Activity.NewSeriesDescActivity.AnonymousClass6.AnonymousClass1 */

                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                if (NewSeriesDescActivity.this.youTubePlayer != null) {
                                    NewSeriesDescActivity.this.youTubePlayer.play();
                                        
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {         
                            
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, AdaptiveTrackSelection.DEFAULT_MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_BUFFER_REEVALUTATION_MS);
                }
            }
```